# Triggering release pipeline from build pipeline and pass in the build number

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I would like to have a manual stage in a build pipeline that triggers a release pipeline and passes build number.  Is it possible to accomplish this without having to add extensions from marketplace?  I am pretty new to Azure, our organization just switched from Bamboo, so I am still getting acquainted with Azure DevOps Thanks!

Comment: You can generate build number under option tab of your build agent. please read this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Answer (score 0):

We can’t directly call the variable of the build pipeline in the release pipeline, as a workaround, we can store the variable to artifact->publish artifact->download this artifact in the release pipeline, then we can use the build variable in the release pipeline.